# Asked to develop an iphone app that uses GPS navigation - realistic expectations?

Tags: iphone, ios, navigation, gps, mapkit

I'm quite new to iphone development, and been asked at work about the feasibility of an app that would involve plotting custom routes on Google maps (I can manage this though a web page), and the app itself would show users a selection of routes they can navigate using a GPS-style (turn by turn) navigation screen.

The routes would have markers that would trigger specific information, such as landmarks, etc. Again, I can have these configured through Google maps on a webpage.

The question is how would you approach this sort of app? Start from scratch or build it on any existing platform? Any tips would be appreciated, as I'm at a loss where to start.

Comment: see this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299703/creating-turn-turn-navigation-iphone-app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the MapKit official Google Maps API for iPhone for the map and routes, but you can't make turn-by-turn software with their API (license terms).

The app, as they want it, is not feasible.

Answer (score 5):

You should read through Google Maps Terms of Service, [Google Maps Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/iphone/terms)

As I understands it in section 10.9 you are not allowed to use the MKMapView to do turn-by-turn navigation.